# How to generate 107 th/s

Tags: mining-hardware

I was recently looking over some bitcoin specs for a friend who wants to create a miner and would like to get no less than 1 Bitcoin per month.

According to:

https://www.cryptocompare.com/mining/calculator/btc?HashingPower=107&HashingUnit=TH%2Fs&PowerConsumption=1250&CostPerkWh=0.0

I would need to generate 107Th/s googleing I have not found out what kind of hardware can generate that number.

Am I looking in the wrong place?

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if the term "hardware" properly describes the scope you are asking about. To reach a hashrate of 107 TH/s, you'd need at least 9-10 ASIC miners at a total purchasing price of more than $20k.

Meanwhile the following image gives an impression of what you're competing with:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The current highest hashrate machine is the Antminer S9 and it does 13.5 TH/s. To get more hash rate, you will need to buy several machines. You don't need to have all of your hashrate in one machine.